# Validate Enum values occur once and only once

Tags: java, arraylist, junit, enums

I have an enum and an object I would like to validate for uniqeness in a junit test.

For example, I have an enum Colors, shown below:

```
 public enum Colors{

    Yellow("This is my favorite color"),
    Blue("This color is okay"),
    Orange("I do not like this color"),
    Green("I hate this color");

    private String value;

    Colors(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I also have an ArrayList named ColorList, which contains Color objects with two properties: value and description. I would like to validate ColorList to test that there are four Color objects which contain the values within the enum. I would like my test to fail if either:

1. A value exists within the Enum that is not within the arrayList
2. A value exists within the arrayList that is not within the Enum

Comment: Do you have to use a `List`? You could use [`EnumSet<Colors>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) instead; that would guarantee that there's only one of each enum value in the set. If you need all values to be included, you can construct one through [`EnumSet.allOf(Colors.class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf(java.lang.Class)).

Comment: I believe using an EnumSet<Colors> requires Colors to be extended from java.lang.Enum, however I cannot modify Colors in this case

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper According to [The Java™ Tutorials - Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html): *All enums implicitly extend `java.lang.Enum`.* --- The Java Language Specification [§8.9. Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) says: *The direct superclass of an enum type E is `Enum<E>`.*

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper, the purpose of `EnumSet` is holding `enum`s, so you can definitely use it like that. Can you use a `Set` instead? It is usually a more logical collection for enums than `List`.

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper, "requires Colors to be extended from java.lang.Enum"? But it _is_ an `enum`! So the problem is ...?

Comment: When I try to declare the EnumSet I receive the following error from my debugger: `Type parameter 'com.company.project.Color' is not within its bound; should extend 'java.lang.Enum<com.company.project.Color>'` My declaration is `EnumSet<Color> colorEnumSet = EnumSet.allOf(Color.class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want best with an `EnumSet`. This will ensure you have all the colors once and only once, and nothing else besides.

```
EnumSet<Colors> allColors = EnumSet.allOf(Colors.class);
```

Here is my playing around in case it helps:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.EnumSet;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TempTest {

    @Test
    public void x() {
        EnumSet<Colors> allColors = EnumSet.allOf(Colors.class);
        assertEquals(4, allColors.size());
        assertThat(allColors, contains(Colors.Yellow, Colors.Blue, Colors.Orange, Colors.Green));
        for (Colors c : allColors) {
            System.out.println(c.name() + " (" + c.getDescription() + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Which gets a green bar and prints:

```
Yellow (This is my favorite color)
Blue (This color is okay)
Orange (I do not like this color)
Green (I hate this color)
```

By the way, I had a compile error in Eclipse: your list of enum values ends with a comma instead of a semicolon.

Also, on a few points of style, I don't know if you are able to change the enum, but, if you can, the normal convention in Java is to have enum values in `ALL_CAPS` and to make the enum class name singular (rather than plural)—e.g. you might call it `public enum NamedColor { YELLOW, RED; }`. You might also rename `value` as `description` to make its purpose clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below junit test cases which will fail in your specified cases.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

enum Colors {

    Yellow("This is my favorite color"), Blue("This color is okay"), Orange(
            "I do not like this color"), Green("I hate this color");

    String value;

    Colors(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class JunitSample {

    private List<Colors> smallList;
    private List<String> largeList;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        smallList = new ArrayList<Colors>();
        largeList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Not keeping yellow in smallList.
        smallList.add(Colors.Blue);
        smallList.add(Colors.Green);
        smallList.add(Colors.Orange);

        largeList.add("Blue");
        largeList.add("Green");
        largeList.add("Orange");
        largeList.add("Yellow");
        largeList.add("Red"); // Red is not defined in Colors Enum class

    }

    @Test
    public void testColorsWhichAreNotThereInEnum() {

        for(String value : largeList){
            Assert.assertNotNull("value not available", Colors.valueOf(value));
        }

    }
    @Test
    public void testColorsWhichAreNotThereInSmallList() {

        for(Colors color : Colors.values()){
            Assert.assertEquals("Color not availale in list",true, smallList.contains(color));
        }

    }

}
```